# ALSA does not find sound devices as user but can as root after kernel upgrade

Tags: upgrade, audio, kernel, alsa

Using Archlinux with x86_64 after kernel upgrade to 3.5.3-1, there is no sound, and ALSA run as user shows no sound devices.  The proper kernel modules are loaded, and both dmesg.log and lspci show the hardware was detected (twp Geforce 560Ti in SLI & nvidia MCP55 on mainboard, all use snd_).

The following termout shows the following:

```
⋯$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:252: no soundcards found...
⋯$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC1200 Analog [ALC1200 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: ALC1200 Digital [ALC1200 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_2 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_2 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_2 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_2 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

A bug has been filed but I'm curious as to how a user is blocked from seeing the sound devices, the ALSA configuration was not changed?

The [ALSA Information Script v 0.4.61](http://pastebin.com/xfKnQvC4) for this system.

Comment: Have you checked that your username is shown in `getfacl -t /dev/snd/*`?

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem and [grawity's](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) answer showed me the right path to resolve it.

This lists your user name groups, with `[]# id [your-user-name]`.

And, `getfacl -t /dev/snd/*` gives you all you have to know about user names and groups that can access `snd` hardware, and if you user name doesn't belong to that group then add it with, e.g., `[]# usermod -a -G [group] [user_name]`

More on users and groups you can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/).